# Woocommerce api only display product id

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

Hi everyone just a quick question here, i have success displayed woocommerce's product via api, below are the code

```
<?php

include_once 'wc-api-php-master/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;

$woocommerce = new Client(
  '', 
  '', 
  '',
  [
      'wp_api' => true,
      'version' => 'wc/v2',
      'query_string_auth' => true // Force Basic Authentication as query string true and using under HTTPS
  ]
);

try {
    // Array of response results.
    $query = new WC_Product_Query( array(
        'return' => 'ids',
    ) );
    $products = $query->get_products();
    print_r($products);

    // Last request data.
    $lastRequest = $woocommerce->http->getRequest();
    $lastRequest->getUrl(); // Requested URL (string).
    $lastRequest->getMethod(); // Request method (string).
    $lastRequest->getParameters(); // Request parameters (array).
    $lastRequest->getHeaders(); // Request headers (array).
    $lastRequest->getBody(); // Request body (JSON).

    // Last response data.
    $lastResponse = $woocommerce->http->getResponse();
    $lastResponse->getCode(); // Response code (int).
    $lastResponse->getHeaders(); // Response headers (array).
    $lastResponse->getBody(); // Response body (JSON).

} catch (HttpClientException $e) {
    $e->getMessage(); // Error message.
    $e->getRequest(); // Last request data.
    $e->getResponse(); // Last response data.
}

?>
```

but it will display all the details include product id, product name, slug etc, how do i just want to display products id?

Thank for help!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code and you will receive only ids of products

```
$query = new WC_Product_Query( array(
    'return' => 'ids',
) );
$products = $query->get_products();
print_r($products);
```

It will only get ids of all products.

Comment: its doesnt work, i upload my full code for you to refer

Comment: i have updated my question, you can have a look, thank you~

Comment: add $product instead of $woocommerce in both request and response and it should work

Comment: $lastRequest = $woocommerce->http->getRequest();

Comment: $lastResponse = $woocommerce->http->getResponse();

Comment: $lastRequest = $products->http->getRequest();
$lastRequest->getUrl(); // Requested URL (string).
$lastRequest->getMethod(); // Request method (string).
$lastRequest->getParameters(); // Request parameters (array).
$lastRequest->getHeaders(); // Request headers (array).
$lastRequest->getBody(); // Request body (JSON).

$lastResponse = $products->http->getResponse();
$lastResponse->getCode(); // Response code (int).
$lastResponse->getHeaders(); // Response headers (array).
$lastResponse->getBody(); // Response body (JSON).

its correct?

Comment: add exit; after print_r($products); and let me know what you get

Comment: its still cant work,
$woocommerce = new Client(
  '', 
  '', 
  '',
  [
      'wp_api' => true,
      'version' => 'wc/v2',
      'query_string_auth' => true // Force Basic Authentication as query string true and using under HTTPS
  ]
);

This part i still need to change it into $products instead of $woocommerce? because after i change ti $products it doesnt work also